# How to loop through association with a Draper decorator method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

I have a TripDecorator which decorates a Trip object. A Trip has many Activities.

I'd like to create a TripDecorator method that generates a list of activities belonging to a specific Trip.

How can I convert this:

```
<h5>Activities</h5>
<ul>
<% @trip.activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= content_tag :li, activity.name %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<%= @trip.activities_list %>
```

I'd like nothing to appear if no activities exist. Is this abstraction possible with Draper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is trivial.

```
class TripDecorator
  decorates :trip

  def activities_list
    return if activities.empty?
    h.content_tag(:h5, "Activities") +
    h.content_tag(:ul) do
      activities.map do |activity|
        h.content_tag(:li, activity.name)
      end.join
    end.html_safe
  end
end
```

You just end up concatenating `content_tag` calls to generate your markup, and you can short-circuit the method if there aren't any activities to loop over.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. To prevent the <li> tags from appearing, the map block needed 'end.join.html_safe'